# .Net framework upgrade from 4 to 4.5.2

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, .net-framework-version

We currently have a Winforms application targeting .NET Framework 4.

When trying to upgrade to 4.5.2 we get an error:

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

How do we go about the upgrade?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: That often indicates your project uses the obsolete `packages.config` for NuGet packages. Not a surprise, but you have to migrate to PackageReference now, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference

Comment: You should post your csproj file.